# encounter error DROP when db name has '-'

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

When I want to delete the db named wordpress-db,
I encounter error dropping them.

[enter error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4c3x.png)

Is '-' a escape character or something?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a quoted identifier since `-` character is not permitted in the unquoted form.

```sql
DROP DATABASE `wordpress-db`;
              ^            ^
```

See [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html)

> Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers:
>   ASCII: **[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)**

Comment: That's because you used single quotes instead of **backtick** symbol as I showed in the answer.